# Forest f = new Forest(new Tree[]{m,p});?

Tags: java, constructor

Im a Java beginner and I don't understand the following statement

```
Forest f = new Forest(new Tree[]{m,p}).
```

What I understand is that we construct a new `Tree` inside of a forest but the following expression `{m,p}` I dont understand. What baffles me are these type of brackets `{`. I thought that you always used `()` for a constructor.
An explanation would be great.

PS.

```
Mango Tree m= new Mango Tree;
Pear Tree p = new PearTree();
```

Comment: Here you  are constructing an array of type `Tree`in which you initially put `m`and `p`

Comment: What's the "PS" part about? It wouldn't compile for multiple reasons.

Comment: it means post scriptum.

Answer (score 3):

`new Tree[]{m,p}` creates an array of `Tree`s containing two `Tree`s - referenced by `m` and `p`.

It is equivalent to:

```
Tree[] trees = new Tree[2];
trees[0] = m;
trees[1] = p;
Forest f = new Forest(trees);
```

or to:

```
Tree[] trees = {m,p};
Forest f = new Forest(trees);
```

Answer (score 1):

Curly braces are used to inizialize arrays.

```
int[] anArray = {0, 1}
```

is equivalent to

```
int[] anotherArray = new int[2];
anotherArray[0] = 0;
anotherArray[1] = 1;
```

Of course is the same for the Tree data type